Error: read ETIMEDOUT how do I trace the initiator of this error in Backstage Nodejs Application?
Backstage instance with Nodejs --- (I will be creating backstage specific issue with relevant details but here I am wondering on nodejs - how do I get better trace of failing process.)
This is an interesting one, "something" is throwing an exception but not able to trace what is it?
What is happening - intermittent time few times in a day application pod crashes with log mentioned below. We have it running in AKS - so when the replica crashes - it will restarts new one!
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error: read ETIMEDOUT
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
    at TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:128:17) {
  errno: -110,
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'read'
}

Node.js v18.20.0

What I have done?

Enabled the debug log to analyze what else is going on.
Reviewed places where we are using the Promises/fetch calls to make sure exceptions are handled.
Introduced the OTEL sending logs to SignalFx(APM) to review events/traces more closely. We do find lot more interesting information there but nothing yet pointing to this Crash.
Underlying framework is Backstage - we do have some deprecated stuff we are due to migrate/upgrade, but doesn't mean it will fix it, if we don't know the causer well. (we have in todo list regardless in our backlog.)
Yet not added, but we are also going to add quantum metric to trace the user session around this time to see what is going on from the frontend.
already looked into adobe analytics at different time to narrow down the usage - but no good lead there too.

My question here is - what else can be set or looked into that get us better trace on what is a root cause here? Why it is not telling how it end up throwing this unhandled exception?
I am also going to create issue on Backstage project with relevant data points to backstage, end of the day it is Nodejs app and really stuck on to determine the causer of this unhandled exception!
